# To Implement KVC validattion method, override -(BOOL)validateIvar:error: or -validateValue:forKey:error:?

Tags: objective-c, ios

The former is described in the KVC Prog Guide, but missing from iOS API installed with Xcode 4.0.2 (with iOS 4.3 SDK) for Snow Leopard which lists the latter.
This is for iOS 2.0 or newer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both. For key named `foo`, you can either implement a specific method

```
-(BOOL)validateFoo:(id*)ioValue error:(NSError**)error {
        ...
}
```

or,  a non-specific method

```
- (BOOL)validateValue:(id *)ioValue forKey:(NSString *)key error:(NSError **)outError {
      if([key isEqualToString:@"foo"]){
           ...
      }else{
          return [super validateValue:ioValue forKey:key error:outError];
      }
  }
```

It is perfectly sensible that you didn't find `validateIvar:error:` in the API documentation, because the part `Ivar` needs to be changed for each key. You don't find every method called `setFoo:` for keys `foo` you defined in the system API reference, do you?

Comment: You're right, of course. What am I thinking? Noobbish mistake.

Comment: No problem at all, @Global nomad. We learn only slowly, one by one. Good hacking!

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks, saved me from my own temporary insanity and probably lots of time chasing an imaginary problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should only implement methods following the pattern `validate<Key>:error:` (which can be done even in a category). Don't override `validateValue:forKey:error:`, and do not call `validateValue:forKey:error:` from within a validation method. You will cause an infinite loop. This is covered in the [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html) documentation and [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdValidation.html) documentation, as well as within the Foundation headers. `validateValue:forKey:error:` is the designated entry point into validation, both for Frameworks like CoreData and your applications.

Code that wishes to perform validation *should* invoke `validateValue:forKey:error:` rather than the custom validation method directly.

For example:

```
if ([[self model] validateValue:&text forKey:@"name" error:&validationError]){
    [[self model] setValue:text forKey:@"name"];
} else {
    [self didFailWithError:validationError];
}
```

This should *not* be done from within an accessor method. An action method is the perfect place to do this.

A working example can be seen [here](https://github.com/quellish/KVCValidationExample)